# Media driver is missing when installing Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, installation, drivers

After downloading windows 8 install ISO with ***Windows 8 media creation tool*** I booted the ISO from my USB to install windows but when I clicked "install" an error said "***A media driver on your computer is missing***"  How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same behaviour when trying to install Windows 10 through from a USB flash formatted with Microsoft's MediaCreationTool. The solution has been to install Windows 10 **from a DVD rather than from the USB**: using a DVD burnt with Microsoft's iso  file, the software did not complain.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem while installing windows 10 using USB and i too downloaded ISO using creation tool only... later again i changed the option like flash drive and downloaded then it worked for me ... may be you can try in this way.

Answer (score 0):

CREDIT TO [IllusionX](https://www.reddit.com/user/IllusionX/)

---

ORIGINAL SOLUTION [HERE](https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/653m0f/installing_windows_10_on_pc_got_missing_media/)

---

If you are using a USB stick to install, When you get to that error, close everything till you get back to the install windows button. At that point unplug your USB stick and place it into another port and install as usual.